# How to handle new line characters in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, teradata

I am exporting table from Teradata to Hive.. The table in the teradata  Has a address field which has  New line characters(\n).. initially I am exporting the table to mount filesystem path from Teradata and then I am loading the table into hive...  Record counts are mismatching between teradata table and hive table, Since new line characters are presented in hive.

**NOTE: I don't want to handle this through sqoop to bring the data** I want to handle the new line characters while loading  Into hive from local path.

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work by creating an external table with the following options:

```
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\001'
ESCAPED BY '\\' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Then I created a partition to the directory that contains the data files. (my table uses partitions)
i.e.

```
ALTER TABLE STG_HOLD_CR_LINE_FEED ADD PARTITION (part_key='part_week53')  LOCATION '/ifs/test/schema.table/staging/';
```

NOTE:  Be sure that when creating your data file you use '\' as the escape character.

Answer (score 0):

Load data command in Hive only copies the data directly into the hdfs table location.

The only reason Hive would split a new line is if you only defined the table stored as TEXT, which by default uses new lines as record separators, not field separators.

To redefine the table you need something like

```
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY  ',' ESCAPED BY 'x' 
LINES TERMINATED BY 'y'
```

Where, x and y are, hopefully, escape characters around fields containing new lines, and record delimiters, respectively

Comment: What do yu mean by escape characters, If the fields have more than more them million records

Comment: For example, a CSV record would put quotes around a column that contains commas itself https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character

Comment: You cannot put records into Hive that are separated by newlines which contain newlines within the data itself. At least, not as plain text. You need to use sqoop otherwise for the correct columns to be parsed and loaded